# Laravel method show in controller resource return null

Tags: php, html, laravel

i just starting to learn Laravel and trying to use controller resource but somehow the show method just return null

**Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class barang extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

**Controller**

```
use App\Models\Barang;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
class DashboardBarangController extends Controller
{
    public function show(barang $barang)
    {
        return $barang
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/daftar-barang', DashboardBarangController::class)
    ->middleware(['auth']);
```

**Blade**

```
<a href="/dashboard/daftar-barang/{{ $barang->id }}">test</a>
```

Comment: The `show()` method is typically used to return a `view`, like `return view('barangs.index, ['barang' => $barang])`. Also, use a `route()` method, not a plain URL, `<a href="{{ route('barangs.show', $barang) }}">Test</a>` (or whatever the route is; run `php artisan route:list` to see what's available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **Route Model Binding - implicit binding**.

If in your resource route URL used with a dash(-) '`/dashboard/daftar-barang/`' your controller bound variable must be like `$daftarBarang`

simple run `php artisan route:list` to list out all routes.

[image]

So in your controller view function must be

```
public function show(barang $daftarBarang){
  return $daftarBarang;
}
```